# Oracle Grants life cycle

Tags: sql, oracle, database-administration

I have created a view or procedure in Oracle database and have given some grants to it.

If I again compiled the created view and procedure will the grants given to it will get revoked?

What is the life cycle of Grants?

Comment: Read this https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/grant_revoke.php

Answer (score 0):

Grant exists until database object would be dropped. You can compile them, you can replace them ("create or replace" statement) - grant will survive.